# Integration using numerical methods

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I have been trying to solve the following integral

$$\frac{1}{60} \int_0^{300} e^{- \left(\frac{x}{60} \right)} \cdot e^{\left(\frac{x-300}{240} \right)^{1.03}}dx$$

I have tried solving by parts as well numerical methods such as the trapezoid rule and Simpson's rule. However, I'm finding that when it comes to the $e^{(\frac{x-300}{240})^{1.03}}$ portion of the equation, when $x=0$ I keep generating a result involving complex numbers because of the $(\cdot)^{1.03}$. I have been told the result is $\approx 0.4310$ though.

Any help much appreicated

Comment: The function is complex valued on that region so it would make sense to give complex values when integrated. Have you tried Mathematica?

Comment: Are you sure about the from of the integrand ? The presence of a power of a negative is unexpected and unlikely. Where does it come from ?

Comment: I haven't tried mathematica specifically, but I did try several online integral calculators and wolfram alpha to no avail.@Jepsilon

Comment: I think I'm sure about the integrand it's from a wait-time probability where X is an exponential distribution and Y is a Weibull distribution. I'll post how I derived it underneath. I actually thought I had done the hard work and wondered why this was tripping me up@YvesDaoust

Comment: P[Z=(X+Y)$>$z]=1-[$\int_0^z \int_0^{z-x}(\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-(\frac{x}{\alpha})})(\eta \beta^{-\eta}y^{n-1}e^{-(\frac{y}{\beta})^{\eta}})$dy dx]

=1-[$1-e^{-(\frac{z}{\alpha})}-\int_0^z(\frac{1}{\alpha}e^{-(\frac{x}{\alpha})})e^{(\frac{x-z}{\beta})^{\eta}}$]dx

P(Z$>$300 minutes)=1-[$1-e^{-(\frac{300}{60})}-\int_0^{300}(\frac{1}{60}e^{-(\frac{x}{60})})e^{(\frac{x-300}{240})^{1.03}}$]dx

Comment: With the extra information, it is now obvious that this integral doesn't solve the problem you've been asked.

Comment: @Harcluna In the integral in your comment above you have taken $e^{-(y/\beta)^\eta}$ with $y = z-x$ and ended up with $e^{[(x-z)/\beta]^\eta}$. This should be $e^{-[(z-x)/\beta]^\eta}$ for which we have no problems with negative numbers inside the power (note that this is just one mistake I saw, I haven't checked that the rest is ok)

Comment: Can we at first scale it with $ \int_0^5 e^{-x+{((x-5)/4)}^\beta} dx$, $\beta= $1.03 ?$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you are totally correct, since for any non integer value of $a$, the integrand is a complex number (plot the real and imaginary parts of the function corresponding to the integrand over the range of integration).

Let us forget the constant term and focus on
$$e^{-\frac{x}{60}}\,e^{(\frac{x-300}{240})^{1+\epsilon}}$$ and develop as a Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$; the result would be
$$f=e^{-\frac{x+20}{80}}-\frac{1}{240}  
   \left(e^{-\frac{x+20}{80}} (x-300) (\log (240)-\log
   (x-300))\right)\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ You could check easily that this is a good approximation of both real an imaginary parts.

Now, if you integrate the above expansion, using special functions, you should get for $\int f\, dx$
$$-80e^{-\frac{x+20}{80}}+\frac{80 }{3 e^5}\text{Ei}\left(\frac{300-x}{80}\right)-\frac{1}{3} e^{-\frac{x+20}{80}}  \left((x-220) \log
   \left(\frac{x-300}{240}\right)+80\right)\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

Here no problem *except* with the logarithm which leads to complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The generalized Weibull distribution is defined to be $0$ for negative values of the base, hence your integral should vanish.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\epsilon = 0.03}$ and $\ds{z^{1 + \epsilon} = \verts{z}^{1 + \epsilon}\expo{\ic\pars{1 + \epsilon}\arg\pars{z}}}$ where $\ds{z \not= 0}$ and $\ds{-\,{ \pi \over 2} < \arg\pars{z} < {3\pi \over 2}}$:

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{{1 \over 60}\int_{0}^{300}\expo{-x/60}
\expo{\bracks{\pars{x - 300}/240}^{1.03}}\dd x}} =
{\expo{-5} \over 60}\int_{0}^{300}\expo{x/60}
\exp\pars{\bracks{x \over 240}^{1 + \epsilon}
\expo{\ic\pars{1 + \epsilon}\pi}}\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
4\expo{-5}\int_{0}^{15/12}\expo{4x}
\exp\pars{-x^{1 + \epsilon}
\bracks{\cos\pars{\epsilon} + \ic\sin\pars{\epsilon}}}\dd x =
\bbx{I_{0} + I_{1}\epsilon + \mrm{O}\pars{\epsilon^{2}}}
\end{align}

---

$$
I_{0} = 4\expo{-5}\int_{0}^{15/12}\expo{4x}
\exp\pars{-x}\dd x = \bbx{{4 \over 3}\,{\expo{15/4} - 1 \over \expo{5}}}
\approx 0.3730
$$

---

\begin{align}
I_{1} & = 4\expo{-5}\int_{0}^{15/12}\expo{4x}\braces{-\expo{-x}\bracks{-\ic + x\ln\pars{x}}}\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\frac{2 \left(-2 \text{Ei}\left(\frac{15}{4}\right)+(-2-6 i)+2 \gamma +9 \log +e^{15/4} \left(-11\mrm{arccoth}\pars{9}+(2+6 i)\right)\right)}{9 e^5}
\\[5mm] & \approx 0.0018 + 0.3730\ic
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbx{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{{1 \over 60}\int_{0}^{300}\expo{-x/60}
\expo{\bracks{\pars{x - 300}/240}^{1.03}}\dd x}} \approx 0.3731 + 0.0112\ic +\mrm{O}\pars{\epsilon^{2}}\,,\qquad\epsilon = 0.03}
\end{align}